# Get all included stylesheets

Tags: xslt

It is possible to get a list of all included stylesheets within the xslt process?

I ask because the whole include/import process is done before the execution and I wonder if I have access to this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet (Main.xslt)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:include href="Sub1.xslt"/>
   <xsl:include href="Sub2.xslt"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
         <xsl:value-of select="document('Main.xslt')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:include/@href"/>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with its included stylesheets Sub1.xslt and Sub2.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="Template1">
      <xsl:text>Template 1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="Template2">
      <xsl:text>Template 2</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>Sub1.xslt Sub2.xslt</root>
```

There may be a different way of doing it; I'm not sure. Also I'm not 100% sure of how the base URI is defined when calling `document('Main.xslt')`, meaning the file name could be resolved relative to the XML instance when you expect it to resolve relative to the XSLT file. In any case, I ran a test with an XML instance residing in a different directory than Main.xslt, and it still worked.

**Addendum:**

For walking the tree recursively, you can do something like this (XSLT1):

```
   <xsl:include href="Sub1.xslt"/>
   <xsl:include href="Sub2.xslt"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <root>
         <xsl:call-template name="WalkIncludes">
            <xsl:with-param name="FileName" select="'Main.xslt'"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="WalkIncludes">
      <xsl:param name="FileName"/>

         <xsl:for-each select="document($FileName)/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:include/@href">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>

            <xsl:call-template name="WalkIncludes">
               <xsl:with-param name="FileName" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, this is an interesting idea. The problem is, that I have more than one stylesheet which have inclucdes, its more like a tree of includes. Edit: Maybe you can archive this with a stylesheet that gets the includes recursive, starting by the root stylesheet. I will try this, thank you very much.

Comment: Well, that can be handled recursively. Are you using XSLT 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

**This short and fully generic transformation produces a hierarchical result (XML tree) that presents all imports/inclusions in any stylesheet tree and avoids infinite loops. Do note that XSLT (both 1.0 and 2.0) allows circular imports**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="pUri" select="'test-strSplitWordDel2.xsl'"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vVisited" select="'|'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:param name="pUri" select="$pUri"/>
  <xsl:param name="pVisited" select="$vVisited"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vVisited" select="concat($pVisited, $pUri, '|')"/>

  <stylesheet uri="{$pUri}">
   <xsl:if test="not(contains($pVisited, concat('|',$pUri,'|')))">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*/xsl:import|*/xsl:include">
        <xsl:with-param name="pVisited" select="$vVisited"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:if>
  </stylesheet>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="xsl:import|xsl:include">
   <xsl:param name="pVisited"/>
     <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)">
        <xsl:with-param name="pUri" select="string(@href)"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pVisited" select="$pVisited"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**For example, when we apply this transformation to the following FXSL stylesheet (func-standardXpathFunctions.xsl):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/04/xpath-datatypes"
 xmlns:xdtOld="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-datatypes"
 xmlns:xdtOld2="http://www.w3.org/2004/10/xpath-datatypes"
 xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt f"
>
<!--
       This module contains the FXSL versions of the "standard" XPath functions

       These are intended as convenience functions, so that they can be passed
       as parameters to other functions (e.g. to f:zipWith())
       or curried and passed as parameters (e.g. to f:map())
-->

 <xsl:import href="func-curry.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-compose-flist.xsl"/>

 <xsl:import href="func-standardArithmeticXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardBooleanXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardStringXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardNodesXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardSequencesXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardAggregateXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardDateTimeXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardXSLTXpathFunctions.xsl"/>
 <xsl:import href="func-standardAxisXpathFunctions.xsl"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<stylesheet uri="test-strSplitWordDel2.xsl">
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-standardArithmeticXpathFunctions.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-standardBooleanXpathFunctions.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-standardStringXpathFunctions.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-standardNodesXpathFunctions.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-standardSequencesXpathFunctions.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-standardAggregateXpathFunctions.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-standardDateTimeXpathFunctions.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-standardXSLTXpathFunctions.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-map.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
               </import>
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                       <import>
                                          <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                       </import>
                                    </stylesheet>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-flip.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
               </import>
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                       <import>
                                          <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                       </import>
                                    </stylesheet>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
   <import>
      <stylesheet uri="func-standardAxisXpathFunctions.xsl">
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-curry.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl">
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-XpathConstructors.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
                                 <import>
                                    <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
                                 </import>
                              </stylesheet>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                     <import>
                        <stylesheet uri="../f/func-curry.xsl">
                           <import>
                              <stylesheet uri="../f/func-type.xsl"/>
                           </import>
                        </stylesheet>
                     </import>
                  </stylesheet>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
         <import>
            <stylesheet uri="func-compose-flist.xsl">
               <import>
                  <stylesheet uri="func-apply.xsl"/>
               </import>
            </stylesheet>
         </import>
      </stylesheet>
   </import>
</stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. This looks very neat and I will try it within my xslt process.