# Can I get a list of all files included in an MSBuild project with XSL?

Tags: xslt, msbuild

Ok. I have a file  application.proj
within that it looks something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="PreBuild;Build;PostBuild;Deploy;PostDeploy;Test" >

    <PropertyGroup>
        <ApplicationName>application</ApplicationName>
        <SolutionPath>C:\Projects\application\Solution\application.sln</SolutionPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="$(SolutionPath)\SharedBuild.properties"/>
    <Import Project="$(ApplicationName).properties"/>
</Project>
```

each of the included projects can also include projects ad infinitum.
So I want some way of drilling down and getting an actual path for each file.

Can I do this in XSL or will I need to revert to C# or something?

Thanks.

Comment: This answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126707/get-all-included-stylesheets/13131428#13131428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

root.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project>  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationName>application</ApplicationName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="project1.xml"/>
  <Import Project="project2.xml"/>
</Project>
```

project1.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project>  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationName>project1</ApplicationName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="project3.xml"/>
</Project>
```

project2.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project>  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationName>project2</ApplicationName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

project3.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project>  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationName>project3</ApplicationName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then this is the sort of thing perhaps?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <projects>
      <!--<xsl:sequence select="test:project(document-uri(.), /Project)" />-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Project">
        <xsl:with-param name="cur-path" select="document-uri(.)" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </projects>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Project">
    <xsl:param name="cur-path" as="xs:anyURI" />
    <project path="{$cur-path}">
      <name><xsl:value-of select="//ApplicationName" /></name>
    </project>
    <xsl:for-each select="//Import">
      <xsl:variable name="path" select="resolve-uri(@Project, $cur-path)" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document(@Project)/Project">
        <xsl:with-param name="cur-path" select="$path" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running against root.xml gives:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:test="urn:test">
   <project path="file:/C:/Dropbox/Public/xsl/recursive/root.xml">
      <name>application</name>
   </project>
   <project path="file:/C:/Dropbox/Public/xsl/recursive/project1.xml">
      <name>project1</name>
   </project>
   <project path="file:/C:/Dropbox/Public/xsl/recursive/project3.xml">
      <name>project3</name>
   </project>
   <project path="file:/C:/Dropbox/Public/xsl/recursive/project2.xml">
      <name>project2</name>
   </project>
</projects>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up doing it in c# in the end as it got pretty complicated in that their were full paths and relative paths, and the relative paths were relative to the file that called the include. But this looks like a great answer...Thanks.

Comment: That's why I used `resolve-uri($relative, $base)` to set $cur-path - it should handle combining an absolute URI with a relative one. The `document()` call can also take a absolute URI as well in fact.

See http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_resolve-uri.html